# Symfony forms (as standalone component with Doctrine) EntityType not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I'm using Symfony forms (v3.0) without the rest of the Symfony framework.  Using Doctrine v2.5.

I've created a form, here's the form type class:

```
class CreateMyEntityForm extends BaseFormType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder->add('myEntity', EntityType::class);
    }
}
```

When loading the page, I get the following error.

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\DoctrineType::__construct() must be
>   an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, none
>   given, called in /var/www/dev3/Vendor/symfony/form/FormRegistry.php on
>   line 85

I believe there's some configuration that needs putting in place here, but I don't know how to create a class that implements ManagerRegistryInterface - if that is the right thing to do.

Any pointers?

Edit - here is my code for setting up Doctrine

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;

class Bootstrap {

    //...some other methods, including getCredentials() which returns DB credentials for Doctrine

    public function getEntityManager($env){

        $isDevMode = $env == 'dev';

        $paths = [ROOT_DIR . '/src'];

        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode, null, null, false);

        $dbParams = $this->getCredentials($env);

        $em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

        return $em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to put `use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;` at the top of your form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34589356/3675759

Comment: @JasonRoman that use statement is present.

Comment: @malcolm I did see that question, but the solution uses the Silex\Application class.  I am not using Silex, and I would like to understand what my class is supposed to do :)

Comment: I didn't see that you weren't using the rest of Symfony, sorry, I'm interested in the solution now too.

Comment: https://github.com/webmozart/standalone-forms

Comment: @malcolm I have seen that example, but it doesn't use Doctrine (so obviously doesn't use an EntityType field)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe me, you're asking for trouble!

`EntityType::class` works when it is seamsly integrated to "Symfony" framework (there's magic under the hoods - via DoctrineBundle). Otherwise, you need to write a lot of code for it to work properly.
**Not worth the effort!**

It's a lot easier if you to create an entity repository and inject it in form constructor, then use in a `ChoiceType::class` field. Somethink like this:

```
<?php
# you form class
namespace Application\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class InvoiceItemtType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('product', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => $this->loadProducts($options['products'])
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['products' => [],]); # custom form option
    }

    private function loadProducts($productsCollection)
    {
        # custom logic here (if any)
    }
}
```

And somewhere in application:

```
$repo = $entityManager->getRepository(Product::class);
$formOptions = ['products' => $repo->findAll()];
$formFactory = Forms::createFormFactory();
$formFactory->create(InvoiceItemtType::class, new InvoiceItem, $formOptions);
```

That's the point!

Comment: Thank you!

For `Symfony 2.8` instead of `configureOption` you need to use `setDefaultOptions`:

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'products' => array()
        ));
    }

Comment: @AndreyTykhonov Nope! Actually, `setDefaultOptions` has been deprecated since Symfony `v2.7` in favor of `configureOptions` (see blog [post](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-form-and-validator-updates#deprecated-setdefaultoptions-in-favor-of-configureoptions) and [Github PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/12891)). So you should to use configureOptions instead. ;)

Comment: How about form submission? The submitted form data is bound to the target entity. Please complete your answer to show the rest

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on the answer by xabbuh.

I was able to implement `EntityType` in the `FormBuilder` without too much extra work. However it does not work with the annotations in order to use `Constraints` directly inside the entity, which would require a lot more work.

You can easily facilitate the `ManagerRegistry` requirement of the Doctrine ORM Forms Extension, by extending the existing `AbstractManagerRegistry` and making your own container property within the custom `ManagerRegistry`.

Then it's just a matter of registering the Form extension just like any other extension (`ValidatorExtension`, `HttpFoundationExtension`, etc).

**The ManagerRegistry**

```
use \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry;

class ManagerRegistry extends AbstractManagerRegistry
{

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $container = [];

    public function __construct($name, array $connections, array $managers, $defaultConnection, $defaultManager, $proxyInterfaceName)
    {
        $this->container = $managers;
        parent::__construct($name, $connections, array_keys($managers), $defaultConnection, $defaultManager, $proxyInterfaceName);
    }

    protected function getService($name)
    {   
        return $this->container[$name];
       //alternatively supply the entity manager here instead
    }

    protected function resetService($name)
    {
        //unset($this->container[$name]);
        return; //don't want to lose the manager
    }


    public function getAliasNamespace($alias)
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException('Namespace aliases not supported');
    }

}
```

---

**Create the Form**

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserType extends AbstractType 
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       $builder->add('field_name', EntityType::class, [
           'class' => YourEntity::class,
           'choice_label' => 'id'
       ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
       $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => YourAssociatedEntity::class]);
    }
}
```

---

**Configure the Form Builder to use the extension and use the Form**

```
$managerRegistry = new \ManagerRegistry('default', [], ['default' => $entityManager], null, 'default', 'Doctrine\\ORM\\Proxy\\Proxy');

$extension = new \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\DoctrineOrmExtension($managerRegistry);

$formBuilder = \Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryBuilder::createFormFactoryBuilder();
$formBuilder->addExtension($extension);

$formFactory = $formBuilder->getFormFactory();

$form = $formFactory->create(new \UserType, $data, $options);
```

---

The above is intended for demonstration purposes only! While it does
function, it is considered [best
practice](https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/) to
[avoid using Doctrine Entities inside of Forms](https://blog.martinhujer.cz/symfony-forms-with-request-objects/). Use a DTO (Data
Transfer Object) instead.

> ENTITIES SHOULD ALWAYS BE VALID
>
> INVALID STATE SHOULD BE IN A DIFFERENT OBJECT
> (You may need a DTO)
> (Also applies to Temporary State)
>
> AVOID SETTERS
>
> AVOID COUPLING WITH THE APPLICATION LAYER
>
> FORM COMPONENTS BREAK ENTITY VALIDITY
> BOTH SYMFONY\FORM AND ZEND\FORM ARE TERRIBLE
> (For this use-case)
> Use a DTO instead

**Doctrine 2.5+** ["NEW" Operator Syntax](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax)

```
class CustomerDTO
{
    public function __construct($name, $email, $city, $value = null)
    {
        // Bind values to the object properties.
    }
}
```

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT NEW CustomerDTO(c.name, e.email, a.city) FROM Customer c JOIN c.email e JOIN c.address a');
$users = $query->getResult(); // array of CustomerDTO
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve your issue is by registering the [DoctrineOrmExtension](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/DoctrineOrmExtension.php) from the Doctrine bridge which makes sure that the entity type is registered with the needed dependencies.

So basically, the process of bootstrapping the Form component would look like this:

```
// a Doctrine ManagerRegistry instance (you will probably already build this somewhere else)
$managerRegistry = ...;

$doctrineOrmExtension = new DoctrineOrmExtension($managerRegistry);

// the list of form extensions
$extensions = array();

// register other extensions
// ...

// add the DoctrineOrmExtension
$extensions[] = $doctrineOrmExtension;

// a ResolvedFormTypeFactoryInterface instance
$resolvedTypeFactory = ...;

$formRegistry = new FormRegistry($extensions, $resolvedTypeFactory);
```

Comment: I've tried it before but using symfony/doctrine-bridge requires a lot of effort in order to work.

Comment: Can you explain how you would "registering the DoctrineOrmExtension from the Doctrine bridge" - I can see that the class is there, but where to use it?

Comment: Thanks...  I'm still unsure how you would build/find a Doctrine ManagerRegistry instance.  I haven't already used this elsewhere - but I appreciate it may be that I don't know enough about Doctrine.  I couldn't find any documentation on the ManagerRegistry class.

Comment: Well, how do you set up Doctrine in your project? A concrete answer depends on your setup.

Comment: I've edited my question with my code for getting Doctrine set up.  The code I've included is pretty much it.

Comment: @xabbuh The real problem is not DoctrineOrmExtension but configure the `ManagerRegistry` as it requires tons of extra work. AFAIK `ManagerRegistry` needs a container, that is what Symfony does via `DoctrineBundle`.